# How to share a file with multiple users using Google Drive SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, sharing

I understand how to share a file with a single e-mail address but how can you share with multiple email addresses in a single operation?

For a single e-mail I use:

```
GTLDrivePermission *perm = [GTLDrivePermission object];
perm.value = @"someone@domain.net";
perm.type = @"user";
perm.role = @"writer";

GTLQueryDrive *q = [GTLQueryDrive queryForPermissionsInsertWithObject:perm fileId:file.identifier];
```

I see that there is a `GTLDrivePermissionList` class but I don't see any examples of how to use it to share with multiple emails.

Answer (score 0):

I think its already late to answer this question. As you have asked about GTLDrivePermissionList. Its main use is to list the given permission property like value, type, role, selfLink, userData etc. for the particular file or folder.

It can be used like following:

```
GTLQueryDrive *query =
[GTLQueryDrive queryForPermissionsListWithFileId:fileId];
  // queryTicket can be used to track the status of the request.
  GTLServiceTicket *queryTicket =
[service executeQuery:query
    completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                        GTLDrivePermissionList *permissions, NSError *error) {
          if (error == nil) {
            completionBlock(permissions.items, nil);
          } else {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
            completionBlock(nil, error);
          }
        }];
```

I was also thinking of a smart way to give permission to multiple email at once. However, Drive SDK doesn't have any methods to do that and therefore, I am iterating it over the email list to give the permission.